# Is it possible to give user font choice from drop down menu?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Is it possible to allow the user to select font from a dropdown box in PowerPoint in VBA? Currently, I have an input box which requires users to correctly input the font name and size

```
FontName = InputBox("Please enter which font you would like for the Month header", "font type", "Calibri")
        FontSize = InputBox("Please enter font size", "fontsize", "12")
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Do you want to display all installed fonts to the user (can be a very long list), or a shorter selection of installed fonts?

Comment: Full list is preferable. Is it possible to have it where you type a few characters which then narrows the list down? Thank you for your help